# Удаление файлов c диска приводит к IOwait 100%. Как снизить нагрузку

Tags: java, c++, python, linux, ubuntu

У меня есть `python`-скрипт, которой обходит папки в некоторой директории на сервере и удаляет старые файлы. Такой скрипт очень грузит север, т.к. файлов много. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ облегчить процессору такую задачу ? Например, если переписать скрипт на компилируемый язык вроде `С++` или `Java`, будет ли толк от этого ?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47697/discussion-on-question-by-faoxis---c----iowait-100).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`iowait=100%`](https://blog.pregos.info/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/iowait.txt) говорит что другие CPU метрики такие как user, sys, idle все нулевые. То есть CPU у вас ничего не делает, а только ждёт пока IO (ввод/вывод) операции закончатся.

Обратите внимание:  ["It is possible to have healthy system with nearly 100% iowait, or have a disk bottleneck with 0% iowait."](http://www.thattommyhall.com/2011/02/18/iops-linux-iostat/) то есть сама по себе эта метрика может ничего не значить. Посмотрите на общее количество IO операций (IOPS) и нагруженность диска (MB/s), например, используя [`iostat`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/225095/1321) и/или [`csysdig`](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/wiki/Sysdig-Examples#disk) (последнее полезно, чтобы широкую картину о текущем состоянии системы получить, присматриваясь к деталям, если необходимо).

Методы, которые могут снизить нагрузку на диск из [@Dave Cheney ответа](https://serverfault.com/a/12714/3933):

- добавить RAM, чтобы было место для файлового кэша
- освободить место на диске (производительность страдает при полном диске на некоторых файловых системах из-за фрагментации)
- подкрутить настройки файловой системы (к примеру, использовать `noatime` опцию при подключении)
- подходящий RAID
- если вы пишите/читаете данные с диска, то можно с размером буфера поиграться

В вашем случае, задача очистки скорее всего фоновая, поэтому можно просто попробовать ограничить количество файлов, которые вы каждую секунду удаляете:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: clean-dir-tree <root-dir>"""
import sys
import time
import pathlib

interval = 1 / 10 # delete no more than 10 files per second    
root_dir = pathlib.Path(sys.argv[1])
for path in root_dir.rglob('*.whatever'):
    try:
        path.unlink()
    except OSError as error:
        print("Can't delete {path}, reason: {error}".format(**vars()),
              file=sys.stderr)
    else:
        time.sleep(interval - time.monotonic() % interval)
```

Чтобы не бороться с другими программами за доступ к диску, можно `ionice` попробовать:

```py
$ ionice -c3 clean-dir-tree .
```

Comment: Сделал `ionice -c3` с процессом. Все работало хорошо около часа, потом диск снова начал неуспевать и сервис начал резко тормозить. Как так получается ? Разве запуск только в `io idle`  не гарантирует нам, что по мере нагрузки сервера на диск, мой скрипт не будет грузить его еще сильнее ?

Comment: @faoxis чтобы осмысленно отвечать на подобные вопросы, необходимо гораздо больше информации (что за железо, сколько VM на этом железе, что они делают, версии, настройки софта  итд). Узнайте [имя планировщика](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-set-io-scheduling-class-priority.html). Также пройдите по ссылкам iostat, sysdig в ответе, чтобы узнать загруженность диска (общие метрики IOPS, MB/s read/write и какие конкретно процессы) в момент времени когда ваш скрипт "не нагружает" систему и когда "грузит".  И особенно полезно посмотреть когда "сервис тормозит", а ваш скрипт вообще не запущен.